# GPS tracking in background using service

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service for listening the GPS locations and I want to display an updated location in Toast, I run the service in other activity by clicking a Button. The service is created successfully but not showing the toast of updated location. Here is code:

```
   public class locationlistening_service extends Service implements LocationListener  {

    static LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;

    private static final String TAG = "Calculations";
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        run();
    }

    private void run(){

        final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        //Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define a listener that responds to location updates
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
              public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
              {
                 recordLocation(location);
              }

              public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

              public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

              public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

        };
    }
public void recordLocation(Location loc) 
{
Toast.makeText(locationlistening_service.this,"Lat: " + String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()) + " Long: " + String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}



    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

        }
```

there is call of service in other activity.

```
public void startButton(View view) {

    startService(new Intent(this, locationlistening_service.class));
}
```

Comment: @THelper thanks for invoking me i will take care of this next time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never calling `requestLocationUpdates()`. Hence, nothing is using your `LocationManager`, `LocationListener`, or `Criteria`.

Please be sure to shut down this service when it is no longer needed.